# Display number of occurrences by day from array of dates

Tags: php, date, multidimensional-array

I am working on a statistics application and I want to output the amount of interactions that happened by day.

I have an multidimensional array that pulls all the information from the database, here is an example:

```
 [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-07-26
                [location] => 709c6d241674ca22
                [action] => start_scan
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-07-26
                [location] => 709c6d241674ca22
                [action] => scan_displayed
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-07-27
                [location] => 709c6d241674ca22
                [action] => lower_device
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-07-27
                [location] => 709c6d241674ca22
                [action] => how_to_use_displayed
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-07-27
                [location] => 709c6d241674ca22
                [action] => raise_device
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-07-28
                [location] => 709c6d241674ca22
                [action] => scan_displayed
            )
```

I can work out what day each interaction occurred on by formatting the date:

```
date('D', strtotime('2012-07-26'));
```

My question is how do I count how many interactions happened on each day of the week and then output it, something like:

```
[Sunday] => 2
[Monday] => 3
[Tueday] => 1
[Wednesday] => 5
[Thursday] => 10
[Friday] => 4
[Saturday] => 9
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array();
foreach($data as $item) {
    $day = date('l', $item['date']);
    $dates[$day]++;
}
var_dump($dates);
```

You may want to declare the array as $dates = array('Monday'=>0, 'Tuesday'=>0 .... ) to get the array containing the days with no interactions.